# Dell Poweredge R640 - System BIOS has halted

Tags: dell-poweredge, pfsense, bios

I'm running pfSense on a Dell Poweredge R640, but after upgrading to the latest bios, it has trouble booting.
The attached picture says that LBR is not available.
Any idea what that means and how to fix it?

Thanks.

[Picture of BIOS crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofYjo.jpg)

Comment: So well, did you do what is suggests? What's in the serial or iDRAC logs? Anyway, are you sure you flashed the right BIOS image?

Comment: The System event log just says "System BIOS has halted"
The BIOS is upgraded through the DRAC web interface, so one should think it's the right one.
The system is rebooted many times. Haven't tried turning the power off completely, though

Comment: contact Dell, as this is a business environment and this site relies on this fact, use the vendor support that you hopefully paid

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is a Dell fault.
I probably need to tell the whole story here:
It all started when I did an upgrade from the 20220729-0600 build to the 20220922-1830 build I think it was.
It failed to boot until I changed kernel in the startup.
After that it booted, but no web page anymore.

And now I can't even boot from the DEV ISO's located here: https://snapshots.netgate.com/amd64/pfSense_master/installer/

But if I try to boot from the STABLE v.2.6. ISO, it seems to make it all the way to where the actual installation starts.

Comment: This is why I think it must be something implemented in the latest DEV builds that causes the server to crash.

Rolling back to an older BIOS does not help either

I would love to try to go back to the 20220729-0600 BUILD / ISO, but that file is not located on that page anymore. If anyone has a link to it, it would be much appreciated.

The 2 exact error messages from the DELL DRAC are:
System BIOS has halted and is unable to continue.
A CPU invalid opcode exception (type 0x06) occurred in the pre-boot UEFI environment. The software attempted to execute invalid code.